# Laravel/PHPUnit: Assert json element exists without defining the value

Tags: json, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5

I'm sending a post request in a test case, and I want to assert that a specific element, let's say with key 'x' exists in the response. In this case, I can't say `seeJson(['x' => whatever]);` because the value is unknown to me. and for sure, I can't do it with `seeJson(['x']);`.

Is there a way to solve this?

If it matters:
Laravel: v5.2.31
PHPUnit: 5.3.4

Comment: Why you didn't try to dump response object?

Comment: @zhilevan: I didn't know I could :-)

Comment: `dump()` is a void method. If I could use it, i'd have to use `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()`. I'll have to check and see if I can use that in a test.

Comment: And one more thing. How would you pass or fail a test then? Because you'd have to break the test request's method chain. I found a `fail` method. But I'll have to look into it more.

Comment: Nope, don't worry about those. You can't get the dump in a variable using `ob_start()` in a test :-(

Comment: I mean tried something like `var_dump($request->getContent());`

Comment: I thought you were referring to the `TestCase::dump()` method. I could get the last response, but there would still be the above question. How to pass or fail a test manually.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<strike>Although it's not optimal at all, I chose to use this code to test the situation:</strike>

```
$this->post(URL, PARAMS)->see('x');
```

X is a hypothetical name, and the actual element key has a slim chance of popping up in the rest of the data. otherwise this nasty workaround wouldn't be practical.

## UPDATE:

Here's the solution to do it properly:

```
public function testCaseName()

{
    $this->post(route('route.name'), [
        'param1' => 1,
        'param2' => 10,
    ], [
        'headers_if_any' => 'value'
    ]);

    $res_array = (array)json_decode($this->response->content());

    $this->assertArrayHasKey('x', $res_array);
}
```

Comment: padding true as the second parameter to json_decode will return the values as array

```json_decode($this->response->content(), true)```

http://php.net/json_decode

Comment: `$this->response` is not available any longer in modern Laravel. Current code would look like `$r = $this->post(...);` then you can work with `$r->getContent()`

Answer (score 46):

May it will be helpful for anyone else. You can write this test for your check response json structure

```
$this->post('/api/login/', [
        'email' => 'customer3@example.com',
        'password' => '123123123',
    ])->assertJsonStructure([
        'status',
        'result' => [
            'id',
            'email',
            'full_name',
        ],
    ]);
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Note when writing Laravel [HTTP tests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/http-tests), it is `$response->assertJsonStructure(array $structure);`

Comment: How would you assert that a child array has X members, or possibly check that it has "no more than X members" or "no less than X members"?

Comment: Please edit your answer from `seeJsonStructure` to `assertJsonStructure`. I wasted time trying to get your answer to work, because that method name does not exist. I would edit the answer myself, but such an edit should be rejected as "not what the author intended".

Comment: @CJDennis Question is tagged with `laravel-5.2`, in that version it was `seeJsonStructure`.